# nodejs - JSON validator for nested JSON Object

Tags: node.js, json

I want to validate for below JSON format:

This is the ideal format.

```
{
    "sectionId": 1,
    "sub_sections": [
        {
            "subSectionId": 1,
            "questions": [
                {
                    "questionId": 1,
                    "answerId": 4
                },
                {
                    "questionId": 2,
                    "answerId": 4
                },
                {
                    "questionId": 3,
                    "answerId": 4
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

`sub_sections` and `questions` are array, so it can be large

I have found some library like `ajv`, but it seems cannot handle nested JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ajv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ajv) uses the [JSON schema](https://json-schema.org/) standard, which is able to handle nested json. JSON schema is part of the OpenAPI standard ([official](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.1.0) spec; more user-friendly [docs](https://swagger.io/specification/) by Swagger).

```
const Ajv = require("ajv");
const ajv = new Ajv();

const input = {
    "sectionId": 1,
    "sub_sections": [
        {
            "subSectionId": 1,
            "questions": [
                {
                    "questionId": 1,
                    "answerId": 4
                },
                {
                    "questionId": 2,
                    "answerId": 4
                },
                {
                    "questionId": 3,
                    "answerId": 4
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

const schema = {
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
        sectionId: {type: 'integer'},
        sub_sections: {
            type: 'array',
            items: {
                type: 'object',
                properties: {
                    subSectionId: {type: 'integer'},
                    questions: {
                        type: 'array',
                        items: {
                            type: 'object',
                            properties: {
                                questionId: {type: 'integer'},
                                answerId:  {type: 'integer'}
                            },
                            required: ['questionId', 'answerId'],
                            additionalProperties: false
                        }
                    }
                },
                required: ['subSectionId', 'questions'],
                additionalProperties: false
            }
        }
    },
    required: ['sectionId', 'sub_sections'],
    additionalProperties: false
};

const validate = ajv.compile(schema);
const valid = validate(input);
console.log(valid); // prints true
```